# Session conditions are not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, if-statement

I have a scenario where I am inserting values in `Gridview` row. So when I insert the row for the first time. Acutally the session value is `""`

But while checking like this

```
if (Convert.ToString(Session["RecdInfo"]) != null || Convert.ToString(Session["RecdInfo"]) != "")
    {
        if (strMode == "M")
        {
            FunFillGrid();
            DtRecdInfo = (DataTable)Session["RecdInfo"];
        }
        DtRecdInfo = (DataTable)Session["RecdInfo"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDataTable();
    }
```

The condition is getting `true` as Instead it should get `false` and go inside the `else` part.

I tried with `Session["RecdInfo"])` but still it is going inside the `IF` condition. any reasons why it is happening like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your condition is not `correct` because if your `session` is `""` than it is not `null` so condition will be `true`.

You can try this first check if `session` is not `null` than check if it is not empty string

```
if (Session["RecdInfo"] != null)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["RecdInfo"] as string))
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: let me try and check this way

Comment: @nad or you can put `&&` instead of `||` in your code it will work

Comment: I know that, but while modification time the condition will not work as the way I wanted

Comment: What is value of `session`

Comment: the value of session is `""`

Comment: is it going in `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["RecdInfo"] as string))`

Comment: yes it is going inside that. but I want that to go in else part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130757/discussion-between-leopard-and-nad).